# What is the best way to achieve the following customized layout?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am kind of wondering what the recommended method is for a customized UI. I have about 5 screens, which will share some of the same elements. One is a topbar, kind of like the navigationbar but different. It has the title on the left, no back buttons, a background image and a logo on the right. The other is a menu at the bottom containing and UIImageView for the bar, 3 UIButtons a the moment opening 2 different screens and one opens the Camera. I want to reuse the top bar and bottom bar on all 5 screens. Sort of like one would use a UserControl on ASP.NET.

Currently I have created 5 ViewControllers, which gives me 5 XIB files that I have to put the same elements on and I have to hook up the same events. I would want to create 2 elements (top and bottom bar) which I can reuse across all screens. Or is there a simpler solution to all of this like e.g. 1 screen pushing different middle parts into it or something like that? Quite the beginner at MonoTouch for that matter, so I'd love to know what the way-to-go for something like this is?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to customise / reuse the standard UINavigationController etc, you could -

1. Create a custom **UIView** in Xamarin / Monotouch for each of your reusable elements, then insert them into each ViewController (programmatically is probably easiest) as required.  This would give some code reuse and is akin to the **UserControl** example you mentioned.
2. Alternatively **for IOS5+** you could create a Custom ViewController Container which has all the common parts in one place and have a single container UIView which you would then switch the rest of your Content ViewControllers as you need to.

I have actually just finished a github example of this which may help -

https://github.com/wickedw/ViewControllerContainer